# Catching the return of window

Tags: c#, wpf, window

There is function in which a new window is opened and shown. I want to put a condition onto the closure of that window. I wrote what I want as a pseudo-code below.

```
private void fnc (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWindow nw = new MyWindow();

    nw.Show();

    // Pseudo code: When (nw.Close()) {do something}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void fnc (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWindow nw = new MyWindow();

    nw.Show();

    // inline
    nw.Closed += (s1, e1) => Debug.WriteLine("Closed");

    // or
    nw.Closed += (s1, e1) =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Closed");

                        };

    // or
    w.Closed += OnWindowClosed;
}

private void OnWindowClosed(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Closed");
}
```

Comment: For the inline version it says: `A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

Comment: @Shibli That is because your func already takes in an e parameter, you will have to name your lambda's something different. I personally prefer to use explicit naming (per my answer), so that you know what the variables actually are (without relying on intellisense)...just change (s,e) to something like (s, eventArgs) or something other than e

Comment: Sorry, my 'e' was clashing with the RoutedEventArgs e.  Changed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx). This will make your code wait until the new window returns.

```
private void fnc (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWindow nw = new MyWindow();
    nw.ShowDialog();
    //Do something when nw returns
}
```

Or, if you do not want to freeze up your parent window, then you will have to attach to the [Window.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx)

```
private void fnc (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWindow nw = new MyWindow();
    nw.Closed += nw_Closed;
    nw.Show();
}

private void new_Closed(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

You could use an inline delegate using lambda expressions if you do not have a method already prepared, also:

```
private void fnc (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWindow nw = new MyWindow();
    nw.Closed += (sender, cancelEventArgs) => 
        {
           //Do Something
        };
    nw.Show();
}
```

Comment: Question is about WPF not Windows Forms